# Function to see if column exists

Tags: oracle, plsql

i am having issue with function to check if column exist in table

Trying to see if v_col is valid column in database table all_tab_cols

```
create or replace function exist(v_col in varchar2) 
 Return integer is
 Res integer:= 0;
 Begin
 v_sql := 'SELECT ' ||
  'COLUMN_NAME ' ||
  'FROM ' ||
  ' all_tab_cols ' ||
  'WHERE ' ||
  'COLUMN_NAME = ''|| v_col||''';
Begin
Execute immediate v_sql;   
Res:=1;
Exception when other then null;
End;
Return (Res);
End;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(exist('ORDER_NUMBER' )); 
END;
/
```

Comment: what is the issue that you encountered?

Comment: "If column exists in table" suggests, to me at least, that you are given a column name **and** a table name, and you must see if a column by that name exists IN THAT TABLE. Do you mean, you need to see if a column exists in ANY table in ANY schema that the user of the function has been granted privileges to? That's what your function is attempting to do (with or without errors doesn't matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need of dynamic SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exist (
     v_col IN VARCHAR2
) 
 RETURN integer is
 res integer;
 BEGIN

 select 1 INTO res from all_tab_cols where 
    column_name = v_col and rownum = 1; --can have >1 columns with same name
 return res;
EXCEPTION when no_data_found THEN
          res := 0;
RETURN res;
END;
/
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with dynamic SQL? I intend to use this within existing function and wanted to see if this was possible using dynamic way.. thanks again

Comment: @user1742716 : What part of it is going to come dynamically? It's preferable not to  use dynamic SQL unless there's no alternative, like in situations where table names and column names are going to be passed at run time. For other scenarios, the ideal solution is to use static SQL.

Comment: If you really want to use dynamic query then you can do it with little change in the above answer: `execute immediate 'select 1 from all_tab_cols where 
    column_name = ''' || v_col || ''' and rownum = 1' INTO res; ` -- Also, Please note that column names are stored in METDATA in upper case, if not quoted with "(double quotes) while creating the table